# pan-tompkins algorithm (moving average integrator)

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing, moving-average, digital-filter

why do we need a moving window integrator in pan-tompkins algorithm , and what is meant by width -information of qrs complex , and how does this latter help us in QRS detection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the moving average filter, the Q and S parts would not contribute at all to the detection of the QRS complex, because they wouldn't affect the size or position of the R peak.  With the moving average filter, the R peak is made higher by the Q and S parts around it.

The "width" of the QRS complex is its duration, i.e., its width on a ECG graph.  The length of the moving average filter needs to be about this long to best accomplish the above purpose without adding P or T segments to the peak.